# How turn off eclipselink sql statement logging in persistence.xml?

Tags: java, jpa, logging, eclipselink

I've configured **EclipseLink** as **JPA** provider for my **Spring** application. The only problem is, it spams the console with SQL statements.

This is my `persistence.xml` configuration:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="jpa-persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
      <property name="logging.level" value="INFO"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I've found references to both `eclipselink.logging.level` and `logging.level` properties in internet, but none of them seems to work. I'm using slf4j, but I don't think it's relevant because I don't need to route SQL output through slf4j, I just want to get rid of it.

How should I configure my `persistence.xml` to stop SQL statement logging?

The version of EclipseLink I'm using:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This is how I instantiate JPA in my Spring application:

```
  <!-- Define EclipseLink JPA Vendor Adapter -->
  <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform"
      value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpa-persistence"></property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
  </bean>
```

Comment: You use a Java EE application ?

Comment: @davidxxx WAR application with Spring deployed on Tomcat... no direct JEE

Comment: Ok thank you. I have just done an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a EclipseLink specific behavior ([reference](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging)).

EclipseLink states :

> By default the log output goes to System.out or your console.
>
> To configure the output to be logged to file the persistence unit
>   property eclipselink.logging.file can be set:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.file" value="output.log"/>
```

> EclipseLink's logging service is plug-able and several different
>   logging integrations are supported including java.util.logging. To
>   enable java.util.logging the persistence unit property
>   eclipselink.logging.logger can be set:

To summarize, you have two solutions:

- defining `eclipselink.logging.file` to avoid polluting the console.
  This is quick hack but personally, I don't use this solution because it creates multiple log files and it makes harder readability of application logs.
- defining `eclipselink.logging.logger`. It is the most flexible solution.

With EclipseLink 2.5+ , [`eclipselink.logging.loger`](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_logging_logger.htm) can specify :

**Custom logger**

> Fully qualified class name of a custom logger which implements
>   org.eclipse.persistence.logging.SessionLog

With this solution you could log through SLF4J and you could also customize the logs in a finer way.
Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/msosvi/1325764) from GIT :

**JavaLogger**

> Uses java.util.logging

`java.util.logging`, the API to avoid...

**ServerLogger**

> Integrates with the application server's logging

**DefaultLogger**

> (Default) Uses EclipseLink's native logger, DefaultSessionLog

Comment: OK I wasn't specific enough. The issue was the Spring and the line:
<property name="showSql" value="false" />
Although there stays 'false', the bean was initiated with 'true', and the properties from persistence.xml were overwritten. Removing the line has solved the issue.

Comment: I understand better. Good :) I though that you would disable EclipseLink logging only in the console but keep it in a log file as you said "The only problem is, it spams the console with SQL statements" I think that enabling showSql l in development/qualification environment is a good practice as it allows to notice queries problem such as n+1 problem or too many executed queries for 1 query.